# Google Calendar Push Notifications to Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-calendar-api

I'm a little stuck here.

I'm trying to hook a Calendar Push Notifications (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) to a Firebase HTTPS Function.
Pratically, I use a FF to create a calendar and I want to watch it for changes.

I authorized my [domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xtxd.png) and compose a request from the first function using the appspot service account ('@appspot.gserviceaccount.com') with the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' but I always received the error message: "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://******.cloudfunctions.net/calendarWebHook"}],"

I'm trying to understand if the service account doesn't have the authorization to create the watcher or the webHook or something else.